# Powershell get list of sub folders and number of files in each in a table format

Tags: list, powershell, file, count

I'd like to create a table showing the number of files in all subfolders named "andre tegninger"
I've found the following code on here which I modified to filter by the sub folder I am interested in.

```
dir -filter "*Andre tegninger*" -recurse |  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | %{ Write-Host $_.FullName (dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count }
```

This works fine but is there a way I can get name of folder and number of files in two separate columns?
Thank you!

Comment: you can select the columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object` to get in separate fields the expected properties :

```
dir -filter "*Andre tegninger*" -recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object -Property FullName, {(dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count}
```

Since -Property expect a property (obviously) You have to use `{}` around `(dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count` to tell powershell it's a calculated expression.

You're getting as output :

```
FullName      (dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count
--------      --------------------------------------
Your list of folders...
```

You can label the fields names to get them some fancy names, such as :

```
dir -filter "*Andre tegninger*" -recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object -Property @{label="Path";expression={$_.FullName}}, @{label="Numer of files";expression={(dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count}}
```

And you get as output :

```
Path     Numer of files
----     --------------
```